# CABasicAnimation doesn't animate the image when i relaunch the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quartz-core

I'm new in ios development. I'm using circle image in my project. In foreground mode circle image rotate very well. Now i tapped the home button.After that i relaunch the app the circle is not rotating.

This is my code:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.duration = 4.0f;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
```

I want to rotate the circle image when i ralaunch the app.